# Checkbox selection not working when using server-side pagination

Tags: angular, typescript, pagination, ngx-datatable

I'm using [ngx-datatable](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable) from [Swilane](https://swimlane.com/) in my Angular 5+ app with the [server-side paging](http://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/#server-paging).

I'm also using the [checkbox selection](http://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/#chkbox-selection) which worked fine in a client-side pagination datatable.

However with the server-side pagination I have an issue: when I change the page I lose the selection of the previous page.

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 3):

I've found the solution to this problem posted on [github](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/issues/874#issuecomment-329474076) by *tylersampson*:

> The issue, I assume, is because new objects are loaded for every page
>   change. So when the selected items are compared to the page, there is
>   technically no match.
>
> For me I managed to solve this by using rowIdentity so that it will
>   compare the "id" field of my data instead of the object.
>   https://swimlane.gitbooks.io/ngx-datatable/api/table/inputs.html#rowidentity

template:

```
<ngx-datatable
    ...
    [rowIdentity]="getId">
```

component:

```
getId(row) {    
    return row.id;
}
```

---

**However, I've improved this solution a little bit.**

In my case the unique identifier of the entity is not always "id", but it's stored in a field variable of the Component's class:

```
id = 'myId'; // this can be overridden
```

so the `getId()` method will look like:

```
getId(row: T) {
    return row[this.id];
}
```

however using it in the template doing `[rowIdentity]="getId"` will **NOT** work because `this` will lose its context and `this.id` will be just `undefined`.

to solve this I need to return a function with its original context:

```
getId(row: T) {
    return row[this.id];
}

getIdFunction() {
    return this.getId.bind(this);
}
```

so now in the template I can use:

`[rowIdentity]="getIdFunction()"`

notice this time the `()` at the end, because now we are actually calling the function `getIdFunction()` which will return the function `getId` binding its context.